# Detect own RDS Session disconnecting/reconnecting

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds, citrix

I would be able to run powershell scripts when users disconnect or reconnect to their RDS/Citrix session.

The scripts must run from the session, with user privileges and environment vars.

I was using a small Citrix utility named [Session State Monitor Tool](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX127491), but this tool is no more supported and not always reliable.

Is there a Windows event, another tool or a Powershell command I could use ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scheduled task and use these triggers:

"On connection to user session"
"On disconnect from user session"

The scheduled task can be deployed via Group Policies Preferences for example
(User Configuration -> Preferences -> Control Panel Settings ->  Scheduled Tasks)

Comment: It looks great, but can I differentiate connecting from reconnecting ?

Comment: I don't know, but you can try with "On workstation unlock" too.